# How to prevent JNI from overwriting GetLastError()

Tags: java, c, winapi, java-native-interface

We are implementing a one-to-one mapping of some `winapi` methods, for the [xidobi](https://code.google.com/p/xidobi/) serial port project. The mapping of the `C` methods to java works as expected, but for an unknown reason `GetLastError()` get cleared.

Here is the **C-Code**:

```
// CreateFile ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_xidobi_OS_CreateFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
    jstring lpFileName,
    jint dwDesiredAccess,
    jint dwShareMode,
    jint lpSecurityAttributes,
    jint dwCreationDisposition,
    jint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    jint hTemplateFile) {

const char* fileName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, lpFileName, NULL);

HANDLE handle = CreateFile(fileName,
                            dwDesiredAccess,
                            dwShareMode,
                            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) lpSecurityAttributes,
                            dwCreationDisposition,
                            dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                            (HANDLE) hTemplateFile);

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, lpFileName, fileName);

return (jint) handle;
}

// GetLastError ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_xidobi_OS_GetLastError(JNIEnv *env, jobject this) {
    return (jint)  GetLastError();
}
```

In **Java** we call the mapped native methods in like this:

```
int handle = os.CreateFile("\\\\.\\" + portName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return handle;
int lastError= os.GetLastError(); //-> sometimes 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

We figured out that if we call `GetLastError()` in C right after `CreateFile(..)` the correct error code is returned. Since the one-to-one mapping is dead simple we assume that JNI or the VM calls `SetLastError()` itself and clears our last error.

We don't want to give up the one-to-one mapping design, so what can we do to solve this puzzle?

Here is a similar question that doesn't help in this case: [CreateFile() returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE but GetLastError() is ERROR_SUCCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665384/createfile-returns-invalid-handle-value-but-getlasterror-is-error-success?rq=1)

Comment: Would calling GetLastError() in Java_org_xidobi_OS_CreateFile() be of any help? Java_org_xidobi_OS_GetLastError() would return the variable where the error code was saved.

Comment: Store the value of `GetLastError()` before the call to `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` and pass it to `SetLastError()` after the caller to `ReleaseStringUTCChars()` ?

Comment: Calling `GetLastError()` right after `CreateFile`would break our one-to-one mapping principle. However storing the last error code works in a single thread world, but not in a multi threading environment. Every thread have its own error code, `GetLastError()` guarantees this, if we store the value we have to implement this behaviour our self in C.

Comment: @hmjd We tried your approach, `ReleaseStringUTCChars()` doesn't clear the error, the clearing happens after `Java_org_xidobi_OS_CreateFile` returns and before `Java_org_xidobi_OS_GetLastError` is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `GetLastError()` will survive whatever the JVM is doing between your native call to `CreateFile` and your native call to `GetLastError`. Therefore you should immediately call `GetLastError` after `CreateFile` and save the value in a thread local slot of your own.

Then your implementation of `GetLastError` will retrieve it from wherever you stored it.

You may wish to rename it LastXidobiError or some such as it will only retrieve an error which was set by a call in your library.

```
// Space to store last error ////////////////////////////////////////////
static DWORD dwTlsIndexLastError = 0;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  _In_  DWORD fdwReason,
  _In_  LPVOID lpvReserved
){


    switch(fdwReason){
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        dwTlsIndexLastError = TlsAlloc();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        TlsFree(dwTlsIndexLastError);
        dwTlsIndexLastError = 0;
        break;
     }
     return TRUE;
}

///// Save the last error. 
///// Call this function after the "real" function whose error you want to report.
void SaveLastError()
{
    TlsSetValue(dsTlsIndexLastError, (LPVOID)(DWORD_PTR)GetLastError());
} 
// GetLastError ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_xidobi_OS_GetLastError(JNIEnv *env, jobject this) {
    return (jint)  TlsGetValue(dsTlsIndexLastError);
}

// CreateFile ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_xidobi_OS_CreateFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
    jstring lpFileName,
    jint dwDesiredAccess,
    jint dwShareMode,
    jint lpSecurityAttributes,
    jint dwCreationDisposition,
    jint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    jint hTemplateFile) {

const char* fileName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, lpFileName, NULL);

HANDLE handle = CreateFile(fileName,
                            dwDesiredAccess,
                            dwShareMode,
                            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) lpSecurityAttributes,
                            dwCreationDisposition,
                            dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                            (HANDLE) hTemplateFile);

// Save the value of GetLastError for the relevant function
SaveLastError();

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, lpFileName, fileName);

return (jint) handle;
}
```

Comment: Your approch creates a new TLS-index, for every new Thread. How to free a unused TLS-index when a Thread is gone and get garbage collected? In other words: How to determine when `TlsFree` have to be called?

Comment: @chriss, The approach creates a TLS index when the DLL is loaded, not for every new thread. If you want to free the TLS (good idea!!!) you should ideally allocate the TLS in the `DllMain` for `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and deallocate it when `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. Otherwise a new TLS will be allocated if the DLL is unloaded and reloaded.

Comment: @chriss, edited the answer to incorporate freeing the TLS as per your comment.